# Problem with ERC20 Faucet

Tags: smart-contract, shimmerevm

I'm new to the IOTA world so forgive me if this question is too basilar ^^'

I'm following the tutorial on https://wiki.iota.org/wasp-evm/getting-started/quickstart/ and i'm trying to deploy a simple smart contract on a local chain.

I create a Metamask wallet and add some Tokens using https://evm-toolkit.evm.testnet.shimmer.network/. When I try to use the EVM faucet (https://evm-faucet.testnet.shimmer.network/) inserting my wallet i receive the message 'Your Request is being verified. Please wait.' and nothing happen.

Am i missing something ?

Thank you for your Patience.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work by now? I don't really have any problems with the faucet. Is your metamask correctly connected to the testnet?